# My webview application is not showing notification popup

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging, popup, android-notifications

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="io.gonative.android"
    android:versionName="1.0.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="29"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>

    <!-- WebRTC Audio and Video -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <!--<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />-->
    <!--<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />-->

    <!-- permissions for push messages -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <permission android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <!-- permissions to block phone calls -->
    <!--<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />-->
    <!--<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />-->
    <!--<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ANSWER_PHONE_CALLS" />-->

    <application
        android:name=".GoNativeApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:logo="@drawable/ic_actionbar"
        android:theme="@style/GoNativeTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true">

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="${admob_app_id}"/>

        <activity
            android:name="io.gonative.android.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:exported="true"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            tools:node="merge">
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".AppLinksActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:exported="true">
            <!--additional intent filters-->

            <!--example: -->
            <!--<intent-filter>-->
            <!--<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>-->
            <!--<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>-->
            <!--<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>-->
            <!--<data android:scheme="http"></data>-->
            <!--<data android:scheme="https"></data>-->
            <!--<data android:host="gonative.io"></data>-->
            <!--<data android:pathPrefix="/"></data>-->
            <!--</intent-filter>-->
        </activity>

        <!-- For file sharing without having to use external permissions. -->
        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true"
            android:exported="false">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/filepaths" />
        </provider>

        <activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service
            android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
       
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@drawable/ic_notification" />
      
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
            android:resource="@color/colorAccent" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.Refex channel"
            android:value="Refex channel" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Hello all , I have developed an android webview application for my website , everything works fine and i have published my application in playstore but the issue is my application is still not receiving any notification , it does not show message notification when it is received , I want my application to show up the notification over the top of the display.

And also i have created a notification and have given all the the permission, Further I have integrated firebase to the application so that it can receive notification .

But the thing is , the notification popup is till not showing . What can I do for this ? what should I do more to receive and display notification over the top of the display ?

Can anyone please help me to resolve this issue

My Android application should have the notification popup over the display when the message is received

Even after giving "post notification" permission and integrating firebase messaging service , the application is not showing the notification popup.